# How to create nested model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am just not to sure how to build a nested form. I have followed Ryan Railscasts but I am unsure on how to create a new instance in my case.

I have the following models

```
Customer,
Book Manager, and
Book
```

The relationship his has follow

```
Customer
    has_many :book_managers, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_managers
Book
    belongs_to :book_manager
    def customer
        book_manager.customer
    end
Book_Manager
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
```

The form his has follow

```
<%= form_for @bookmanager do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :books, Book.new do |builder| %>
  <div>
    <%= builder.label :description %><br />
    <%= builder.text_area :description, :rows => 3 %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">  
    <%= f.label :visible %><br />  
    <%= f.text_field :visible %>  
  </div>  
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

The part that confused me his to create a new instance in the single form. I have a description which belongs to book and I have a isVisible who belongs to book_managers

Here what i am thinking but doesn't seem to be working

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@bookmanager = BookManager.new(params[:bookmanager])
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
```

I also try the following

```
@customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
@bookmanager = @customer.book_managers.build
```

It doesn't work and not sure how to create the relationship. Any help on it is appreciated!

Here the query i did In rails c

```
cust = Customer.first
cust.book_managers.build :visible => true
cust.book_managers.first.books.build :description => 'the odyssey'
cust.save!
```

Seem okay then i did the follow to check

```
cust = Customer.find 1
cust.books              ### This is where the error was given to me
Book.first.customer
```

The error is

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `books' for #<Customer:0xad55afc>
```

Comment: Does it give an error on your console?

Comment: It does now. Ill update what show the error look like

Comment: Following Railscasts Tutorial I should not add a relationship from customer -> books. But many other people seem to suggest to do so with has_many. What his the best way, How should i create a new item. I am very confused on how ruby acts.

Comment: If you need to have something like:  

    `cust = Customer.find(1)`, `cust.books`

You need to have in your `Customer` model a `has_many :books` relashionship.

Comment: That would resolve my console issues, but it doesn't resolve the creation of books and book_manager in one form. How could i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a has_many: through: relationship

```rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_managers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :book_managers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_managers
end

class BookManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :books, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_manager
  def customer
    book_manager.customer
  end
end
```

You can read more http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many